# List view rows not getting clicked?

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a ListView with list of items and trying to print some toast on clicking each row of the ListView but the toast is getting printedwhen I am clicking on the header part of the ListView but not coming when clicking on the rows of the ListView. What can be the issue. I am not able to get as to why it is not recognising the click on the rows of the ListView.

Please help me. Thanx in advance!!!

Here is my code

Main Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ankit.surya1.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="1500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);

        listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_items);

        LstViewAdapter adapter = new LstViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.rowlayout, items);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
/*
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Choose");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.checked);
                final CharSequence[] items = {"Call", "Send SMS"};
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        // t12.setText(items[item]);
                        if (items[item] == "call") {
// write the calll code here......................................

                        }
                        if (items[item] == "Send SMS") {
//write the sms code here..........................................


                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();*/
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:   {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi ki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 1:    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi ki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:   {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi ki", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

header.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#9E9E9E"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Loan #"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Ph No"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Area"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="ROI"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Interest"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="9"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="DaysLeft"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="11"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="SMS Count"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/table1"
            >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

rowlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#9E9E9E"
        >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="text"

            >


        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#000000"


            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"


            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="phone"
            >
        </TextView>


        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="text"

            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="text"

            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="6"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"
            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"


            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="8"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:inputType="number"



            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="9"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"

            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t11"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="10"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"


            >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/t12"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_column="11"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="number"

            >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="list_items">

        <item>Gold__4__Jahn Ibrahim__9556551456__LB Nagar__Hyd__95220__6__2920__22920__-26__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__3__Amit Kumar__9556325566__KpHB __Hyd__20000__3__2920__22580__-4__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__7__Mohan__9556458745__Hitecy__Hyd__95226__3__2920__23570__-5__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__8__Ravi__9556551456__LB Nagar__Hyd__95220__6__2920__278750__-26__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__3__Sunil__9556325566__KpHB __Hyd__20000__3__2920__27540__-4__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__9__Amit__9556458745__Hitecy__Hyd__95226__3__2920__27780__-5__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__5__Mohan__9556551456__LB Nagar__Hyd__95220__6__2920__278740__-26__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__3__Amit__9556325566__KpHB __Hyd__20000__3__2920__22920__-4__0__</item>
        <item>Gold__7__Jain__9556458745__Hitecy__Hyd__95226__3__2920__22920__-5__0__</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: could you put a screenshot ?

Comment: Have you tried log instead of toast.. inside switch case

Comment: where is your adapter class?? What type of adapter you have used???

Comment: what is the use phrase {} for case's in your switch?